# Зачем так сделали..?

Tags: php

Разбираю чужой код начала нулевых...
Зачем так?:

```
$start = '1';  
unset($start);  
session_register("start");
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Если просто сделать

```
session_register("start");
```

то может быть зарегистрированна переменная с непонятным содержимым.

Поэтому добавили `unset($start);`. Но видимо, если переменная не существует, то эта функция выбрасывает предупреждение. Поэтому появилась ещё одна строка, которая явно инициализирует строку.

Comment: т.е. это извращенное название session_start(); ?

Comment: не думаю. Просто видимо кто то защищался от багов и сделал это как смог.